# How to populate referenced documents in mongodb-java-driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

Thanks for reading this

I am referencing a document from a different collection like the following:

```
{"name" : "John", "friends": [

    {"$ref": "profile", "$id": ObjectId("5c54f912fdcdd041c8d4232a")},
    {"$ref": "profile", "$id": ObjectId("5c641b2c8ca9cebfe874c5c9")}
]}
```

My question is how can I get the actual referenced document? For example in `node.js` and  `mongoose` we use `populate()` method in order to do so.

A friend told me this happens automatically in JAVA, so I haven't done anything other than a regular data retrieval and of course searching for a solution. So I get the list and I print the size no problem, but when I try to access a field of the referenced document, I get a null exception error.

```
Document playerDoc = this.PLUIGN.getDatabaseHelper().getCollection('friendzone').find(eq("name", "John")).first();

List<Document> friendsList= (List<Document>) playerDoc.get("friends");

friendsList.size(); // returns 2

for(int i = 0; i < friendsList.size(); i++) {
    if(friendsList.get(i) == null) 
     this.PLUGIN.log("Item " + i + " is null");
    else 
         // HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
     this.PLUGIN.log("LORE: " + friendsList.get(i).getString("lore"));
}
```

Thanks,